# Why is there an error installing the pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I tried to install the pyinstaller with the command `pip install pyinstaller` and got an error:

```
C:\Users\kshnk>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/c9/0b44b2ea87ba36395483a672fddd07e6a9cb2b8d3c4a28d7ae76c7e7e1e5/PyInstaller-3.5.tar.gz (3.5MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.5MB 2.2MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' 'c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\kshnk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11qk42u_\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (24 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
    File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
    File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
    File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
      from pip._internal.models.search_scope import SearchScope
    File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\models\search_scope.py", line 11, in <module>
      from pip._internal.utils.misc import normalize_path, redact_password_from_url
    File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 58, in <module>
      from typing import cast, Tuple
    File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1356, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1004, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python37\python.exe' 'c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\kshnk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-11qk42u_\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

OS: Windows 10 ver 1903

Python 3.7.3

Comment: try downloading the wheel file of pyinstaller from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ then do ``` pip install filename.whl ```

Comment: @AbdeslemSMAHI wow ty, thats work for me

Comment: ok i'll write it as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try downloading the wheel file of pyinstaller from

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

then do

`pip install filename.whl`

Answer (score 4):

## Issue resolved using below installation

i had similar issue. but below installion worked and it install all the dependence!!!

```
pip install pyinstaller==4.0 --no-build-isolation
```

Comment: this is not worked for running `pip install pyinstaller` as administrator on cmd works

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the error comes from `typing.py`.

Upgrading typing module will solve this issue:

```
pip install -U typing
```

or:

```
pip install --upgrade typing
```

Otherwise try removing the package.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the wheel file from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

```
pip install path_to_download.whl

pip install pyinstaller==4.0 --no-build-isolation
```

Answer (score 0):

run CMD as **administrator** and then run the following command on cmd will install successfully

`pip install pyinstaller`